# display openlayers lat/long map bound on page

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to display the bounds of my current extent on the page. I am not too great with javascript. I know it must be related to this:
map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.left, bounds.bottom))

Can't seem to get it. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for map.getExtent(): http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getExtent

This will give you a bounds object in the coordinate-system of your map. The Bounds object (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html) has several methods for getting the bound-coordinates, the simplest beeing toString.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You will likely want to transform those bounds to the epsg:4326 projection to get the "normal" lat/lon coordinates we're all used to.  Especially if you're just starting out I'm assuming you're using a mercator (google/bing/OSM) base map.  Just FYI.  These are all assumptions.

Comment: Good point, forgot to mention that. I am so used to working with WMSes in various UTM zones that I forgot this.